# General info on Resources for Running SQL Server queries

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know of online or otherwise resources for running queries?
My copy of SQL Server did not install correctly, after many attempts on my part.

Does anyone know of any resource in which I can test my SQL queries?
I am in New York City, in case there are public places with SQL Server access.

EDIT: Someone suggested I may be able to run queries with MySQL (including running a query that allows me to create the database I want to query ).

Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33203/discussion-between-tom-v-and-msis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One popular site is [**SQL fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com) that currently provides online test facilities for MS SQL Server 2008 and MS SQL Server 2014 (among others).

Another one is "our very own" [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/new), where you can run arbitrary queries against recent snapshots of the site data on SQL Server.